# Show badges in user profile in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, ios-app

When viewing a user's profile from the iOS app, it would be nice to be able to see what badges they have, instead of just the counts.

Comment: I'd like this, too.

Comment: A good way to do this might be to display a badge list if you click on the badge icon or badge number in a user's profile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a badges list in the iOS app? If not, why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257836/is-there-a-badges-list-in-the-ios-app-if-not-why)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I don't think so. This is specifically about a user's badge list, not the global complete one..