# Is there a badges list in the iOS app? If not, why?

Tags: support, badges, ios-app

As we know, there are 6 tabs on StackOverflow on the regular site, which are "questions", "tags", "users", "badges", "unanswered" and "ask question".

But there isn't "badges" tab in iOS app. Is it? If so, how can I find badges list in iOS app?

Comment: While I understand that the app is not designed to replace the web site, anything we do frequently on the mobile website would be helpful within the app, including this. As @Patrick Hofman suggested, you can make a feature request. I would support it.

Answer (score 3):

The same is true for the android app. I'm guessing it's a design choice: the purpose of the app is to allow for QA activity. The app is therefore optimised for this, allowing you to view, comment on, answer, vote and flag posts.

Personally i don't think that listing the badges should be a crucial feature of the mobile app. In my opinion it can easily be obtained elsewhere. Indeed if you want a list of badges you can always [consult the mobile website page for badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Answer (score 0):

You can't find it since it isn't there. The iOS app isn't a replacement for the website. It is complimentary to the site.

There is a lot you can't find in the app which you can on the site. I guess they didn't find it necessary to implement that feature at the time.

Whether they need to add this tab to the app depends on whether it is deemed helpful to the use of the app. I am not sure about that, but why don't you make a feature request?